# USB C for supply + data

Tags: schematics, usb-c

I am working on a PCB Design and I need one USB power supply and data. I have read about CC1/CC2 configurations but I'm not sure that putting 5.1 kOhm resistors on CC1 and CC2 will work fine. I have seen one PCB Design like my design, but the designer uses two usb ports:

[image: Schematics]

Why doesn't he connect USB2_N and USB2_P directly on DP1, DN1, DP2, DN2?

The designer tells to me this:

"sure you can do that, just means that you may need an adapter if you want to attach a USB device because you are also powering the board through the same connector.
You also need a mechanism to detect the device role which means an extra IC to switch between the host and device role."

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BY the look at the schematic, they are using the usb-c power only on the connector. Just like a Raspberry Pi's cpu board. CC1 and CC2 are connected as a device, but no data.

Comment: But, It is not better all on the same connector for save connectors? If I would want all on the same connector, Should it work connecting USB Data to USB C Data Connectors with that CC configuration?

Comment: Depends on application, but the USB-c is a really cheap 100W connector compared to others that are not massed produced like them. as far as the USB, yes you could connect data lines, however it has to be done with a USB hub controller if you want to share the same data lines with another usb port.

Comment: I want to use the USB only for flashing eMMC of Raspberry, there are other USB ports for other uses, I supose I don't need any hub, right?

Comment: I wouldn't see why not, unless the eMMc card does not have a dedicated pins for programming.

Comment: The designer of the board tells to me this:

"sure you can do that, just means that you may need an adapter if you want to attach a USB device because you are also powering the board through the same connector
you also need a mechanism to detect the device role which means an extra IC to switch between the host and device role"

Comment: That is if you are trying to make a compute board with one connector only. Like a tablet style board. There are many ways they could have set up this architecture, but since this is a simple chip set, like most of these, they would have to switch the entire unit into flash mode. Unlike a desktop computer that loads its cmos dynamically and have ways to switch on the write pin by software.

Comment: Someone could set up the processor so that the usb-c can switch over to that function, but they would have to make their own cmos hardware image for the system so they can make a programming mode exist like other non dynamic cmos programming methods (hold down button combination to enter cmos programming menu/mode) That would change the "role" from normal operation. It was probably easier to implement the simple usb controller, and switch out the role by a  jumper. Because they would have to tie up i/o lines just for this, instead of having it for GPIO.

Comment: I am not that familiar with their hardware, but if they made available an e-prom boot bus on the GPIO, There should be a way to add a cmos boot e-prom to this bus.